# Java - Using for loops to read user input

Tags: java, for-loop, user-input

In Java, I am having trouble running multiple loops using a single sequence of user-inputted integers. Individually, they run fine individually but together it prints out incorrect numbers.

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this problem.

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SequenceTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integers. " + 
        "Enter a non-integer to terminate");
    int sequence = in.nextInt();

    //Print One
    int min = sequence;
    while(in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if(input < smallest)
        {
            smallest = input;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(smallest);  

    //Print Two
    int max = sequence;
    while(in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if(input > max)
        {
            max = input;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max); 

    //Print Three
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    while(in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if((input %2) == 0)
        {
            even++;
        }
        else
        {
            odd++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( even);
    System.out.println(odd);

    //Print Four
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (in.hasNextInt())
    {
        Int input = in.nextInt();
        total = total + input;
        count++;
    }
    double average = 0;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        average = total / count;
    }
    System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Comment: I love that "looping" is now an algorithm.

Comment: Prints incorrect numbers how? What's the output? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Also: what do you mean by "running individually" and "running them together"?

Comment: you should think about one look with multiple conditional statements.

Comment: Obligatory: your first step in situations like these should be **starting the debugger**. (Or adding a whole lot of `println()` statements.) Don't just stare at your code and try to figure out what it *might be* doing, but look, directly, at what it *actually is* doing. Notice the differences between what you think should happen and what is happening, and if they don't move you forward, include them in your question.

Comment: It might help if you showed us your attempt at combining the loops (funny thing - this looks a LOT like the current assignment for the class I'm currently TAing...)

Comment: Johnny is obviously in a programming intro course - thinking like a computer takes practice and doesn't come naturally to everyone. Interesting link though @Eric .  On another note, please show us your attempt, and what exactly goes wrong so we can figure out how to help you understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very fragmented, but it looks like you can achieve what you want with one loop since the loop condition is the same in all of them. This, of course, is only based on the vague description you gave us.

```
while(in.hasNextInt()) {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        if(condition1) {
            //do stuff
        } else if (condition2) {
            //do other stuff
        } else if (conditionN) {
            //do other other stuff
        } else {
            //last of the stuff to do
        }
}
```